# Python: How can I add a doxygen comment to a function with a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, doxygen, python-decorators

Where do I have to insert the doxygen comment?:

```
 ##
 # @brief Text
 @classmethod
 def foo(self):
     pass
```

or like this:

```
 @classmethod
 ##
 # @brief Text
 def foo(self):
     pass
```

Comment: Always, just try. Both are possible. I don't know what the python community would think is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docstrings are preferred when documenting functions and classes in Python. Fortunately, Doxygen supports this way of documenting as well. To do so, simply use an exclamation mark `!` at the start of your docstring.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(init=False)
class SomeClass:
    """!
    @brief ...
    @details ...
    """
    _name: str   #<! ...
    _amount: int #<! ...

    def __init__(self, name: str, amount: int) -> None:
        """!
        @brief ...
        @details ...
        @param[in] name ...
        @param[in] amount ...
        """
        self._name = name
        self._amount = amount

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        """!
        @brief ...
        @return ...
        """
        return self._name

    @property
    def amount(self) -> int:
        """!
        @brief ...
        @return ...
        """
        return self._amount

    @amount.setter
    def amount(self, value: int) -> None:
        """!
        @brief ...
        @param[in] value ...
        """
        self._amount = value

    @staticmethod
    def addone(arg: int) -> int:
        """!
        @brief ...
        @details ...
        @param[in] arg ...
        @return ...
        """
        return arg + 1
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use for your test / answer? From version 1.8.20 onward there is the setting `PYTHON_DOCSTRING` with the meaning:   By default Python docstrings are displayed as preformatted text and doxygen's special commands cannot be used. By setting `PYTHON_DOCSTRING` to `NO` the doxygen's special commands can be used and the contents of the docstring documentation blocks is shown as doxygen documentation. I think this should be mentioned in your answer as well.

Comment: @albert I haven't tested it but the documentation of Doxygen explicitly states: *"When using """ none of doxygen's special commands are supported and the text is shown as verbatim text see \verbatim. To have the doxygen's special commands and have the text as regular documentation instead of """ use """! **or** set PYTHON_DOCSTRING to NO in the configuration file."* So according to their own documentation, it should work without setting `PYTHON_DOCSTRING` to `NO`.

Comment: I'm missing in your comment with which doxygen version you tested it.

Comment: Note in your answer at some places you use `""""!` instead of `"""!`

Answer (score 0):

When I have:

```
    def __init__(self, name: str, amount: int) -> None:
        """
        @brief ...
        @details ...
        @param[in] name ...
        @param[in] amount ...
        """
        self._name = name
        self._amount = amount
```

and

```
PYTHON_DOCSTRING = YES
```

this results in the documentation:

[image]

When using

```
PYTHON_DOCSTRING = NO
```

this results in:

[image]

which is the same as when using `"""!`.

Tested with: 1.9.4 (5d15657a55555e6181a7830a5c723af75e7577e2)